# Trying to mount from freebsd to centos NFS server

Tags: centos, nfs, freebsd, centos6.5

I cannot map my FreeBSD client to my CentOS NFS server.

**On trying to mount I get:**

- `RPCPROG_NFS: RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Unable to send`

**Version of client is:**

- FreeBSD 8.0-RELEASE

**Version of server is:**

- CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

**Settings all look fine in:**

- `/etc/exports`
- `/etc/hosts.allow`
- `/etc/hosts.deny`

**id root from freebsd lists:**

- `uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),5(operator)`

**id root from centos lists:**

- `uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

`rpcinfo` on NFS server lists `portmapper`, `mountd`, `nfs`, `nfs_acl`, `nlockmgr`.

Other CentOS boxes on the same network are able to connect to the NFS server.

The FreeBSD client I am trying to mount from has several mounts to another FreeBSD NFS server on the same network.

I amma stuck, pls help...

Comment: Start with the obvious: 1. Both systems haven't had updates installed for years. 2. You're trying to use NFSv3.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for the comment. These are legacy systems I would like to avoid having to update. Could you please elaborate  on what you mean with point 2? Thanks!

Comment: *Unable to send* probably indicates there's a packet filter blocking communications in between.

Comment: NFSv3 is ancient, creaky, unreliable, and long obsolete. The only real reason to use it is if you have to speak to something that is also ancient, creaky, unreliable and long obsolete and thus doesn't understand NFSv4 (which, dating back to 2003, is merely _mature_; and besides, it works properly over TCP). Neither your client nor server appear to qualify as such, despite not having been updated in quite a while.

Comment: Hi Michael, cheers for the explanation on nfs, how do you know its v3 btw? Also do you have any suggestions on how to solve the problem with freebsd vs centos nfs mounts? Thanks!

Comment: Hi drookie thanks for the suggestion! There is no firewall, other machines on the network can mount it. My feeling is its a centos vs freebsd issue.  But if not where do you think should I look for hints visavi packet filtering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be the firewall on the client.

ipfw had rules to allow ip to the other nfs servers but not the one I was trying to connect to.

Took a while, here is the resource I used:
https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/firewalls-ipfw.html

Thanks to user drookie for pointing me in the right direction!